# Showing that a submodule of $\mathbb Z$ is free

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

$\textbf{Definition:}$ A free module is a module that has a basis.

If I wanted to show that a $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $\mathbb Z$ is free, what would be a way of doing so?

Since a $\mathbb{Z}$-module is just an abelian group, then any submodule of a $\mathbb{Z}$-module is also an abelian group.  Is it enough to just find a basis for this $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule and thus showing that the submodule is free?  It is also the case that $(1)$ is a generator for a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Or shall I consider some map $f: (1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$?

Thank for the help!!!!

Comment: What $\,\Bbb Z - $ submodule are you talking about? What is the module? If the whole module is free, then any submodule will also be free. The other way around isn't true.

Comment: @Joanpemo the problem states:  Show that every $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $\mathbb{Z}$ is free.

Comment: This is a nontrivial theorem.  What related results and ideas have you seen?

Comment: @EricWofsey  We've studied ideals, quotient rings, modules, the concept of torsion.  We have also covered the first two chapters of Intro to Commutative Algebra by Atiyah MacDonald.

Comment: @mathamphetaminesI f you already know that any subgroup of $\;\Bbb Z\;$ is of the form $\;m\Bbb Z\;$ , for some $\;m\in\Bbb Z\;$ , then the problem is trivial, as such a submodule has a very easy basis: $\;\{m\}\;$ , as you can readily check.

Comment: @Joanpemo So finding a basis for the submodule suffices?

Comment: @mathamphetamines Indeed so, and even by the definition you gave.

Comment: @Joanpemo Thank you for the help!!!